# Did Swami Vivekananda worship a personal deity?

Tags: worship, vivekananda

I have read that Ramakrishna Paramahamsa would often teach devotion to less advanced disciples but would only teach Advaita to Vivekananda.  Did Vivekananda worship any personal deity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, He did. He worshipped Maa Kali. But He never taught Kali worship to anyone. He considered being His personal affair. He mentioned: "The secret of my Kali-worship will die with me".

He wrote a beautiful poem: **Kali the Mother:**

> The stars are blotted out,
>
> The clouds are covering clouds,
>
> It is darkness vibrant, sonant.
>
> In the roaring, whirling wind
>
> Are the souls of a million lunatics
>
> Just loose from the prison-house,
>
> Wrenching trees by the roots,
>
> Sweeping all from the path.
>
> The sea has joined the fray,
>
> And swirls up mountain-waves,
>
> To reach the pitchy sky.
>
> The flash of lurid light
>
> Reveals on every side
>
> A thousand, thousand shades
>
> Of Death begrimed and black —
>
> Scattering plagues and sorrows,
>
> Dancing mad with joy,
>
> Come, Mother, come!
>
> For Terror is Thy name,
>
> Death is in Thy breath,
>
> And every shaking step
>
> Destroys a world forever.
>
> Thou "Time", the All-Destroyer!
>
> Come, O Mother, come!
>
> Who dares misery love,
>
> And hug the form of Death,
>
> Dance in Destruction's dance,
>
> To him the Mother comes.

He also wrote one beautiful hymn: Amba-Stotra in Sanskrit.

Ref:1. Nivedita Lokamata,Sankari prasad Basu, Vol 1.page 298-300
2.CW of Swami Vivekananda

Comment: The "Sri Mahishasura Mardini Stotra" book published by the Rk Mission has this Amba Stotram composed by Swamiji

Comment: Can you add source for this statement: "The secret of my Kali-worship will die with me"? Poem cannot be proof of personal deity.

Comment: @sv. i have alrwady included the biogaphy of nivedita as ref

Answer (score 5):

Swami Vivekananda's devotion towards Goddess Kali is mentioned in his short biography too.

[Here](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda1.pdf) is the PDF (A short biography of Swami Vivekananda by Swami Tejasananda).

> **Following the pilgrimage to Amarnath the Swami’s devotion concentrated itself on the Mother, and he was soon blessed with a
>   wonderful vision of Kali the Divine Mother.** While his vision was
>   most intense he wrote ‘Kali the Mother’—a poem, where he is seen at
>   his best. After this experience he retired alone abruptly on September
>   30 to the Coloured Springs of Kshir Bhavani where he practised severe
>   austerities. He was found completely transfigured when he returned to
>   his disciples after a few days.